# Issues installing private npm packages

Tags: npm, font-awesome, npm-install, bower, npm-registry

I have a project with dependency on some private repo (fontawesome) for which our org has taken a license

While all the other packages are installed via our internal registry, the fontawesome dependency is installed via npm.fontawesome.com
So, in my `.npmrc`, I have the following

```
registry=http://frs-mycompname.net
proxy=http://approxy.mycompname.net:8080
https-proxy=http://approxy.mycompname.net:8080
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=TOKEN
```

As you can see, there is a proxy defined as well.
While other dependencies download fine, for some reasons, I am unable to install the fontawesome dependency at all.

The auth key is fine (checked with someone else who has the same key)

Is there any way by which I can verify if something might be blocking access to the fontawesome registry URL ?
How can I verify the same using any command or something?

Comment: I tried some months ago using several registries for npm very similar as you. I ended up  migrating all the dependencies in one registry, because I was not able to configure npm to use more registries. An option would be to use Verdaccio as registry (https://verdaccio.org/). Verdaccio can be configured as registry in the .npmrc and the Verdaccio itself can have more registries. If `http://frs-mycompname.net` is an Artifactory, then using virtual repositories can be a great option.

Comment: Actually, in my case, even the fontawesome dependency was working fine (alongwith dependencies from the other registry)...But suddenly it stopped working...I am suspecting like the URL is not accessible probably because of firewall or something....need a way to verify if that is the case...

Comment: What kind of error do you get on the command line while running `npm install`? You mention above that you checked the authkey, how did you do that?

Comment: I am getting a 404 for the package when doing npm install

Comment: A possibility could also be, that when the fontawesome was working fine, it came from a local cache. I mean from `%AppData%\npm-cache` or the `node_modules` of the project. And as a cache clean was performed the fontawesome was not in the cache anymore, and from that point it stopped working.